# Using Automapper to create an additive-only conditionally copy for every property

Tags: .net-core, automapper

I have two objects of the same type.  I want to conditionally copy values from objectA to objectB using Automapper (essentially creating an additive only copy between two objects of the same type).  I've looked at the conditional mapping and other converter types, but I don't want to specify this for every single property of the object.  I would like to copy every property using the exact same logic.

- If source property is NULL, do not copy
- If target already has value, do not copy
- If target is NULL, copy from source
- If both the source and target properties are a list, then only add missing items to the target list as target may have items not in the source list which need to stay.

I know I could create a configuration by specifying these rules for every single property, but I would like to know if it's possible to define these rules globally for every property being mapped so that I could make one generic version of this mapping configuration.

I feel like all I need is the ability to specify a func where automapper passes in both the source and target values and I can simply make a decision based on equality between them using the above mentioned logic.

```
    public static TOutput CopyAll<TInput, TOutput>(TInput input, TOutput output)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<TInput, TOutput>().ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition((src, dest, srcValue, destValue) =>
            {
                return (srcValue != null && destValue == null);
            }));
        });

        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        return mapper.Map<TInput, TOutput>(input, output);
    }
```

Comment: Research ForAllMembers and conditional mapping.

Comment: That works really well Lucian.  I'm still trying to figure out how to copy items from properties that are a list type in objectA to an existing list in objectB so that I'm only adding new ones (not removing items in the list that only exist in objectB).

Comment: When mapping to an existing collection, the destination collection is cleared first. If this is not what you want, take a look at AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: Yea I don't want the collection cleared is key.  Some basic option to not clear before mapping missing items.  I'll take a look

Comment: Took a look at AutoMapper.Collection, but it actually deletes items in the existing collection that are not in the source.  Need option to not delete.

Comment: I don't know exactly what's possible with AutoMapper.Collection. But if all else fails, you just have to handle the collections case in your own code.

Comment: That would work, but does auto mapper allow you to essentially write your own mapper handler for the collection or maybe I just abaondone automapper all together to build a non-destructive copy between two objects.

Comment: Well, AM is not really a cloning library, but it could work. You can for example create a map from `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable`, or smth like that.